# How do you stop Google Inbox from trimming content in your email?

Tags: html, css, email, gmail

Gmail is notorious for [using clumsy scripts to trim signatures off the end of emails](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/vfuhlHRsoWQ). However using Google Inbox, they seem to have made this behavior even worse by trimming out content in the middle of the email - not only the signature at the end.

The Gmail issue could be resolved by adding random strings into the html to prevent the scripts from detecting 'similar content' and thus not trimming anything. Example:

```
<div class='gmail_hack'> <%= DateTime.now.to_i %> </div>
```

This is a dirty solution but it worked. It does not however work in Google Inbox.

How is it possible to prevent Google Inbox from trimming content in my email?

Comment: Ehm, use a proper email client such as Thunderbird?

Comment: @MrLister I would love to but unfortunately I am the sender, not the receiver

Comment: If you are the sender you should let the receiver decide if they want to want to collapse content or not.